# data type mismatch in criteria expression in access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have connected outlook mails inbox with access and then created a query, where I wrote this code:

```
KeyID: Str(Left(Right([Contents],Len([Contents])-InStr(1,[Contents],"-")+4),10))
```

to get a specific string from the mail subject line, which is working fine but when I am using

```
"Like ("xyz*")"
```

in criteria section of query or creating relationship with another table taking `KeyID` as the reference column, getting an error:

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

when i am running the query. Your help would help to solve. Thanks.

```
    SELECT Inbox.Subject, 
Inbox.Contents, 
Inbox.Received, 
Inbox.[Sender Name], 
Left(Right([Contents],Len([Contents])-InStr(1,[Contents],"-"‌​)+4),10) AS KeyID 
    FROM Inbox 
    WHERE (((Left(Right([Contents],Len([Contents])-InStr(1,[Contents],‌​"-")+4),10)) Like 'OMY*')) ORDER BY Inbox.Received DESC;
```

Comment: `Like` works for text fields. Where do you use it? For calculated field `KeyID` or for other not text field?

Comment: I am using "Like "XYZ*"" in KeyID field.

Comment: SELECT Inbox.Subject, Inbox.Contents, Inbox.Received, Inbox.[Sender Name], Left(Right([Contents],Len([Contents])-InStr(1,[Contents],"-")+4),10) AS KeyID
FROM Inbox
WHERE (((Left(Right([Contents],Len([Contents])-InStr(1,[Contents],"-")+4),10)) Like 'OMY*'))
ORDER BY Inbox.Received DESC;

Comment: Please post some example *Contents* as I cannot reproduce your issue with sample data of my own.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
"Like ('xyz*')"
```

Comment: I tried both, with or without brackets, none of these are working. Interestingly, the column is text, If i try to establishing relationship between field of Query1 KeyID and Query2 KeyID, where both are text, same error is showing even if criteria (Like ("xyz*")) is not used.

Comment: Try using single quotation  instead of double like 'xyz*'

Comment: Thanks to all for your support, sad to say that it does not work even with or without single or double quotation.